# Rotation of object (using its images) on button click using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I am currently using Jquery Plugin for showing the rotation of any object using the objects images(images are captured from every angle).rotation is working fine on mouse click.The thing is i want to make rotation possible with the help of buttons(i.e.,Left ,right,top,down buttons) .On clicking left button the images must show the rotation clockwise or left direction and vice-versa.Can you help me with this please

I have try following code :

```
$(function(){ 
      $('#image').reel({ 
          frames: 20, 
          frame: 14, 
          footage: 10, 
          rows: 13, 
          row: 8, 
          cw: true, 
          inversed: false, 
          speed: 0, 
          images: 'Drilbit/Drilbit_normal_###.png',
          cursor: 'move', 
          preloader: 3, 
          draggable: true, 
          wheelable: true, 
          throwable: true, 
        //steppable:true, 
     }); 
});
```

Comment: can you show what you have try??

Comment: $(function(){
   $('#image').reel({
          frames:      20,
          frame:       14,
   footage:    10, 
          rows:        13,
          row:         8,
   cw:         true,
   inversed:   false,
          speed:       0,
          images:      'Drilbit/Drilbit_normal_###.png',
   cursor:     'move',
   preloader:  3,
   draggable: true,
   wheelable: true,
   throwable: true,
   //steppable:true,
   });
  });

Comment: this is the reel function that belongs to the reel plugin wch i have used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reel plugin documentation is described in [this](http://test.vostrel.cz/jquery.reel/docs/jquery.reel.html#stepLeft-Event) (annotated source code) process.

Triggering `stepRight`, `stepLeft Events` on reel object performs adequate actions.
You should bind this Event calls to your control buttons.

```
$(function(){ 
    var reelObject = $('#image').reel({ 
        //required options
        steppable:true 
    }); 

    $('#button-right').click(function (){
        reelObject.trigger('stepRight');
    })

    $('#button-left').click(function (){
        reelObject.trigger('stepLeft');
    })
});
```

The same idea can be used for [up/down events](http://test.vostrel.cz/jquery.reel/docs/jquery.reel.html#stepUp-Event).

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/99sdH/) is jsFiddle with demonstration.

`//edit: added jsFidle for demonstration.`

Comment: hey thanks for the idea.. i have read the source code .. but StepLeft and stepRight options are by default set to true.Stil If got another way without the help of this plugin then please let me know

Comment: hey thanks but can you help me with stepUp and stepDown.. plz

Comment: Plugin documentation have up/down events marked as `new in version 1.3`. On author site is only version 1.2. You should look at his [github repo](https://github.com/pisi/Reel) in development branch (the events is present in source files. But can't say if is stable).

Comment: Yes i reported this issue on github , i referred the same in development branch its working there,but whats the problem with my code. is it the code issue or version issue?